# How to show datapicker for datatype in asp.net MVC2 using telerik in edit mode

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-2, datepicker, telerik-mvc

I have an MVC application and using telerik grid for performing the listing,add,edit operation.I am using popup mode for edit/add .I want to show the datepicker for date datatype in the edit and add operation.

I have created a partial view for the datepicker using telerik as:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"
            Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
<%= Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
        .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty))
        .HtmlAttributes(new {
            id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty) +
                 DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString()
        })
        .Value(Model > DateTime.MinValue ? Model : DateTime.Today)
%>
```

and using `UIHint` added referred in model class but it is giving error:
`The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.`

So how can i show the datepicker while performing the add/edit operation using telerik.

If there is any other way to show the datepicker then also it is ok.

Thanks in advance

supriya

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting indicates that the string being passed is not a valid DateTime (cannot be parsed).